# Inverse z transform using partial fraction

Tags: z-transform

Here's my attempt at an inverse z transform using partial fraction. I was going through my textbook and it stated that all the z terms need to be converted to z inverse before using partial fraction expansion, yet I have hit a roadblock. Please advise.

[image: Part 1]
[image: Part 2]

Answer (score 2):

Since the Z-transform is linear, you can just use a Transform table to find the discrete time equivalent of
$$ X(z) = \frac{-7/3}{z-1} + \frac{22/3}{z-4}.$$
Look separetly for an inverse of,
$$\frac{-7/3}{z-1} = A(z), $$ and 
$$ \frac{22/3}{z-4} = B(z).$$
Then add the two inverses to get the discrete time \$x[k] = a[k] + b[k]\$.

Comment: But the books says the answer is: delta [n] /2 - 7[1^n]/3 + 11 [4^n]/6. Where did the third term come from?

Comment: Looking at what Chu wrote, that delta term is there to make \$ x[0] = 0 \$ isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

For example:

\$\small Y(z)=\large\frac {a}{z-b}= \small z^{-1}\large \frac{az}{z-b}\$

hence:

\$y[k]=a\:b^{k-1}\:u(k-1)\$, where \$ u(k-1)\$ is the unit step sequence.